# Binding Datasource View to Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to get my data to show in a DataGrid.  I am using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 and working with a WPF application.

I created a new datasource, I chose a "View" that I created in SQL Server.  I selected the dropdown on that View in the data pane.  I chose the dropdown and clicked on DataGrid.  Then I dragged it to a user control.  When I run the application, the headers show but the result set does not.  When I run the view in SQL server it returns a result set.  What am I doing wrong?

This is the XAML in the User Control

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myviewsViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:myview, CreateList=True}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource myviewsViewSource}">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="561,121,0,0" Name="myviewsDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="mnemonicColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Mnemonic}" Header="Mnemonic" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="toolColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Tool}" Header="Tool" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="filterColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Filter}" Header="Filter" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="createdColumn" Header="Created" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Created, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="typeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Header="Type" Width="SizeToHeader" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Here is my C# code:

```
    public partial class ScanControl : UserControl
{
    public ScanControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       

    private void UserControl_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            //Load your data here and assign the result to the CollectionViewSource.
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource myCollectionViewSource = (System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["myviewsViewSource"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you get data to an ObservableCollection and bind this collection to the data grid's source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a few things in order to data bind.

1) Make sure you have set your DataContext to `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

2) You need to change the ItemsSource binding in your DataGrid to: `ItemsSource="{Binding SomePropertyName}"`

3) You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged'

4) To implement this property use the following:

```
    #region INotifyPorpertyChanged Memebers 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
```

5) Make an property of type `ObservableCollection` of the type of object the the DB is returning. This property is the property the DataGrid is bounded to.

ex:

```
private ObservableCollection<SomeDataType> _myPrivateData;
public ObservableCollection<SomeDataType> SomePropertyName { get { return _myPrivateData; } set    { _myPrivateData= value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SomePropertyName"); } }
```

That takes care of the data binding part. Now every time you reset the collection that DataGrid is bound to your DataGrid will update because the NotifyPropertyChanged is called.

Comment: This was very helpful.  Thanks for taking the time.